# TTL is bigger than default TTL on the system when ping 8.8.8.8

Tags: linux, ping

I'm running ping on my Linux system. I checked the default TTL on my system:

```
i@cloudshell:~$ sudo sysctl  -a | grep ttl
net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl = 64
```

and I tried to ping 1.1.1.1 and everything is normal:

```
i@cloudshell:~$ ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=7.75 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=7.26 ms
```

but when I try to ping 8.8.8.8, I get a TTL which is larger than my default TTL:

```
i@cloudshell:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=1.15 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=114 time=1.36 ms
```

I'm thinking about any router at the middle of the way, may increase the TTL? is that possible?
From my knowledge, router should always decrease the TTL, but not increase.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* ping is showing you the TTL on the response packet back from the server.  Pings are not simply an echo, the server you ping reads the ping request and sends back a matching response which is a new packet with a new TTL.

Routers will, by default, subtract 1 from the TTL of every packet and drop any packet reaching 0.  That’s the whole point of TTL.

It’s theoretically possible for a router to increase the TTL but I don’t know of any hardware that would actually do this. It could really break things by creating infinite routing loops.

So what you are seeing here is the TTL setting of google DNS (8.8.8.8) and cloudflare (1.1.1.1) minus any routers in-between.